# Genymotion on slackware 14.1 is possible to run latest version?

Tags: genymotion, slackware

On my slackware 14.1 the version 2.5.2 works fine
The latest 2.6.0 give me this error

```
dic 8 00:49:17 [Genymotion] [Fatal] Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50401) with this library (version 0x50501)
```

I have latest qt5,is there a trick to run latest genymotion on slackware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to upgrate your slackware version to **"slackware-current"** using **slackpkg** tool.

```
# slackpkg update
# slackpkg install-new
# slackpkg upgrade-all
# slackpkg clean-system
```

And then upgrade KDE (including qt libraries) to latest version from
[Alien's 'ktown' repository](http://alien.slackbook.org/ktown/current/5/).

Comment: Is not a good solution,current is stil on RC status,and unofficial too.